# How to return the UPPER of a column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to return the UPPER of a column?

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Table'[Name])
```

This returns column Name, I want the UPPER of Name.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 'Table'[Name] ),
    "NAME", UPPER ( 'Table'[Name] )
)
```